# How to access an SMB file server using Ruby

Tags: ruby, scrape, samba

I need to periodically scrape a spreadsheet that resides on another server in my company's network. (Legit exercise from inside company's network. No blackhat stuff.) The IP address is visible, but I'm told the relevant server uses Samba.

I'm looking for a Ruby script that can access one or more relevant files for subsequent scraping. Have tried the Sambal gem w/o success thus far.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the Ruby SMB library http://rubysmb.sourceforge.net/intro.php

Most of the Samba bindings for Ruby are old. Here is a relatively updated one.

https://github.com/fumiyas/ruby-net-smb

Comment: Not yet. Library not updated since 2007? Dubious...

Comment: @bjpcjp On the hind sight, it could also be that the library has stabilized so the author stopped making updates. I have edited my answer to include a relatively newer resource.

Comment: I'll give it a shot & report back. Thanks!

Comment: @bjpcjp please report back.

Comment: no longer a valid request. we've moved on.